# How to use the GPU for faster runtime?

Tags: python, encryption, gpu

I am trying to implement the Arnold Cat Map algorithm to encrypt an image. I have managed to do it, but I also wanted to try it out on the GPU to see the difference in speed. From what I have searched, it seems I have to use Numba, PyTorch, Cupy libraries to make it work on the GPU. I have tried with numba and PyTorch, but I don't think I am doing it right.

If you could please guide me to a solution, it will help me a lot!

Thanks

```
import cv2
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
import time
import torch

def transform(img, num):

rows, cols, ch = img.shape
if (rows == cols):
    n = rows
    img2 = np.zeros([rows, cols, ch])
    for x in range(0, rows):
        for y in range(0, cols):

            img2[x][y] = img[(x+y)%n][(x+2*y)%n]
    cv2.imwrite("C:\\Users\Iani\Desktop\imagine2.jpg", img2)
    return img2

else:
    print("The image is not square.")

def run():
   img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\Iani\Desktop\imagine.png')
   for i in range (1,26):
      img = transform(img, i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    run()
    end = time.time()
    print("Rularea a durat {0}".format(end - start))
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use Numba or CuPy, the goal is the same: to accelerate a NumPy solution, by doing work in parallel. The `np.zeros` call isn't going to be the problem. It's all those individual pixel operations. You're not really using NumPy there; it's just copying one pixel at a time.

In this particular case, it looks like you're going to need "stride tricks". Specifically, I think you'll need `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(x, shape, strides, subok=False, writeable=False)` with `strides` such that `img2` is a square subset of the resulting temporary view. Looking at Wikipedia, I think `shape` needs to be `[N*3, N*2]`:
[image]

You can then move to `cupy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to see if CuPy makes it faster.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, Christmas and stuff. I don't understand by: "think shape needs to be [N*3, N*2]". From what i have read, the shape attributes gives us the number of rows and columns. Because my algorithm works only with square images, shouldn't the input of the shape attribute be the number of rows and columns of the original image?  I didn't have the time to code your solution, but i want to make sure that i understand your advice. Thanks!

Comment: @NurciIani: The idea is to first unfold the square at the bottom right, and that unfolding makes it bigger.